# Giving zero indent for inner cell Indent in Aspose Word

Tags: asp.net, ms-word, aspose, aspose.words, aspose.pdf

I am trying to create inner cells in pdf with using aspose words. But I have issues about its style. I need to center and fit my text in cell. But when I set center property for cell it gives some padding automatically.

> I made a sample with MS word as below image: 
>   [image]
>
> This one is that I have created programmatically with using aspose words.[image]

As you can see it doesn't fit when I set center property true for columns.
My inner cell import code is below:

```
Cell cell = table.Rows[j].Cells[i];
cell.CellFormat.RightPadding = 0;
foreach (Paragraph pf in cell.Paragraphs)
{
     pf.ParagraphFormat.LeftIndent = 0;
}
cell.CellFormat.WrapText = false;
builder.MoveTo(cell.FirstParagraph);

builder.InsertCell();
builder.Writeln(tr.Rows[j][i].Value);
builder.EndTable();
```

Which property should I set to fit it in cell, thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret the two screen shots. The page width seems to be the same, but the font size is different, the cell content is different and part of the names is in all caps in the one but not the other. This makes comparison difficult - I'm not sure what we should be looking at? The main difference I see is that the cells of the second table appear to be changing widths to accomodate content (autofit) - you may need to create the table so that this doesn't happen.

Comment: Please set Paragraph.ParagraphFormat.Alignment value as ParagraphAlignment.Center. Hope, this helps. The shared images are not visible. Could you please share your input and expected output documents?  I work with Aspose as Developer.

Comment: @CindyMeister please ignore the font differences. I just need to fit text to cell as first image. But with aspose even if I set left- righ padding zero still it gives default padding. That is the main problem.

Comment: @TahirManzoor text property already has been set as center -for all texts in columns-.

Comment: In the issue description, the images are not visible. Could you please share your input and expected output documents? I will then provide you more information on this along with code. I work with Aspose as Developer.

Comment: @TahirManzoor you can download it from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/noy2qa24ttn82qk/1.PNG?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code example to get the required output. You may modify the table/cell width according to your requirement. I suggest you please read following link to work with tables. Hope this helps you.

[Working with Tables](http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsnet/Working+with+Tables)

If you still face problem, share your input and expected output documents. I will share the code according to your expected document.

```
Document doc = new Document();
DocumentBuilder builder = new DocumentBuilder(doc);
builder.Font.Name = "Calibri";
builder.CellFormat.LeftPadding = 0;
builder.CellFormat.RightPadding = 0;
builder.CellFormat.TopPadding = 0;
builder.CellFormat.BottomPadding = 0;

Table table = builder.StartTable();

// Insert a cell
builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.PreferredWidth = PreferredWidth.FromPercent(33);

//Insert inner table
Table table1 = builder.StartTable();
builder.InsertCell();
table1.Alignment = TableAlignment.Left;
table1.PreferredWidth = PreferredWidth.FromPercent(50);

builder.Write("This is cell 1");
builder.EndRow();
builder.EndTable();

// Insert a cell
builder.InsertCell();
//Insert inner table
Table table2 = builder.StartTable();
builder.InsertCell();
table2.Alignment = TableAlignment.Center;
table2.PreferredWidth = PreferredWidth.FromPercent(50);
builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Center;
builder.Write("This is cell 2");
builder.EndRow();
builder.EndTable();

// Insert a cell
builder.InsertCell();
builder.CellFormat.PreferredWidth = PreferredWidth.FromPercent(33);

//Insert inner table
Table table3 = builder.StartTable();
builder.InsertCell();
table3.PreferredWidth = PreferredWidth.FromPercent(50);
table3.Alignment = TableAlignment.Right;
builder.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
builder.Write("This is cell 3");
builder.EndRow();
builder.EndTable();

builder.EndRow();
builder.EndTable();

doc.Save(MyDir + "Out.docx");
```

I work with Aspose as Developer evangelist.

Comment: thank you, but I couldn't center with this way. I have solved with another way. I added two rows for each name and profession. And I adjusted them.